# Spring Boot @RestController @Autowired null in Unit tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, junit5, autowired

I can't understand why @Autowiring my @RestController class is returning null.
I want to do a basic unit test before doing an integrated test but its failing.
In fact anything that is being @Autowired is showing null in the test package.

I have a very simple test, I just want to see the basic works:

A very simple example:

```
@Component
public class SimpleComponent {

    public int add(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

And the test:

```
class SimpleComponentTest {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleComponent component;

    @Test
    public void givenSimpleComponentShouldNotBeNull(){
        assertNotNull(component);//How on earth does this fail?
    }


}
```

Here is the code from the Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeAccountApi {

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String register(){
        return "Registering!";
    }

}

public class EmployeeAccountApiUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeAccountApi employeeAccountApi;

    @Test
    public void testAutowiring(){
        assertNotNull(employeeAccountApi);//Fails, Can't understand why
    }

}
```

This works with the @Mock annotation:
But I dont want to mock it as that is the class I am unit testing.
I want to test that the method returns a basic string.
Question is why isn't it working?

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class EmployeeAccountApiUnitTest {

    @Mock
    private EmployeeAccountApi employeeAccountApi;

    @Test
    public void testAutowiring(){
        assertNotNull(employeeAccountApi);//This works
    }

}
```

Even if I get the Employee Service that clearly worked and tested in the previous test also is null in this class:

```
public class EmployeeAccountApiUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeAccountApi employeeAccountApi;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService service;

    @Test
    public void testAutowiring(){
        //assertNotNull(employeeAccountApi);
        assertNotNull(service);
    }

}
```

Why is @Autowired null in the Test?
Mocking is working fine

Plenty of similar questions but they are too specific and not provide any basic information

Comment: how is that class in which it doesn't work instantiated? That's your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get it

Comment: well when you mock something, you are supposed to inject it into the context either using @Bean, or if you are MockBean

Comment: The Mocks are working fine, the auto wiring isn't, I wanted to perform a simple unit. I have updated my answer with even a simple example of what I am not understanding. This isn't about mocks

Comment: Please check updated question, I am very surprised by why it isn't working,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) has to be used on the test class for Spring to load your ApplicationContext and wire things up. Without out this there's nothing for Spring to inject.

You can use [@WebMvcTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) on the test class to focus your tests only on the Web Layer.

There's a whole bunch of annotations that allow you to "slice" your ApplicationContext up lots of other ways for testing various other parts of your application.

Spring's documentation and tutorials are really very good. You should check them out.

[Testing the Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/)

Answer (score 2):

@Autowired only works if you are spinning up the application context for your application. Annotate the test class with `@SpringBootTest`, which tells the test to start the entire spring application context, and it should work.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Just on a side note, I heard this loads the entire application context. So if I wanted to do a basic unit test like this I would need to instantiate it manually right?

Comment: I mean, for a unit test you should mock away anything that is a call for another class or an external resource. So in that case, don't annotate with @SpringBootTest but instead change the tests to use mocks, and rather use mockito to tell what a call to the mock should return. E.g. `when(anotherService.methodCall()).thenReturn(new MyMockObject());`

Comment: @theMyth if you instantiate it manually, it's autowired members will be null, for the same reason